# CollectionView function "didSelectItemAt" is not getting called

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have multiple ViewController with a CollectionView each. In every CollectionView I want to do something after a Cell is selected. In one ViewController it's not working, but in every other it works.

I checked the delegates, datasource and registration of Cells multiple times but it's like in the other ViewControllers too so I cant see, why it's not working. Also I dont have any Buttons in the Cell, I saw before that you can't use "didSelectItemAt" when you have Buttons in Cell. Additionally I commented out the part where I add the Subviews and constraints, but it still didn't get called.

ViewController which is not working:

```
class HomeController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, HomeControllerDelegate {

    lazy var eventCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 25
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.dataSource = self
        cv.delegate = self
        return cv
    }()

    let eventCellId = "EventCellId"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(eventCollectionView)

        eventCollectionView.anchorWithConstantsToTop(view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 94, leftConstant: 25, bottomConstant: 25, rightConstant: 25)

        eventCollectionView.register(EventCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: eventCellId)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 24
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = eventCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: eventCellId, for: indexPath) as! EventCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 245/255, green: 245/255, blue: 245/255, alpha: 1)
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 233/255, green: 233/255, blue: 233/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 2
        cell.homeControllerDelegate = self
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        if view.frame.width < 415.0 {
            return CGSize(width: view.frame.width - 50, height: view.frame.width - 60)
        }
        else if view.frame.width < 828.0 {
            return CGSize(width: (view.frame.width / 2) - 50, height: (view.frame.width / 2) - 60)
        }
        else {
            return CGSize(width: (view.frame.width / 3) - 50, height: (view.frame.width / 3) - 60)
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Selected Event Cell")
    }
}
```

ViewController which is working:

```
class FavoritesController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, FavoritesControllerDelegate {

    lazy var favoritesCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 5
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 235/255, green: 235/255, blue: 235/255, alpha: 1)
        cv.dataSource = self
        cv.delegate = self
        return cv
    }()

    let favoritesCellId = "FavoritesCellId"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(favoritesCollectionView)

        favoritesCollectionView.anchorToTop(view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor)

        registerCells()
        sideNavigationController = ""
    }

    fileprivate func registerCells() {
        favoritesCollectionView.register(FavoritesCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: favoritesCellId)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 6
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = favoritesCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: favoritesCellId, for: indexPath) as! FavoritesCell
        cell.backgroundColor = .white
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 2
        cell.favoritesControllerDelegate = self
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 125)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Selected Favorites Cell")
    }
}
```

Constraints are added with this extension of UIView:

```
extension UIView {

    func anchorToTop(_ top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, left: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, right: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil) {

        anchorWithConstantsToTop(top, left: left, bottom: bottom, right: right, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0)
    }

    func anchorWithConstantsToTop(_ top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, left: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, right: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, topConstant: CGFloat = 0, leftConstant: CGFloat = 0, bottomConstant: CGFloat = 0, rightConstant: CGFloat = 0) {

        _ = anchor(top, left: left, bottom: bottom, right: right, topConstant: topConstant, leftConstant: leftConstant, bottomConstant: bottomConstant, rightConstant: rightConstant)
    }

    func anchor(_ top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, left: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, right: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, topConstant: CGFloat = 0, leftConstant: CGFloat = 0, bottomConstant: CGFloat = 0, rightConstant: CGFloat = 0, widthConstant: CGFloat = 0, heightConstant: CGFloat = 0) -> [NSLayoutConstraint] {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        var anchors = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

        if let top = top {
            anchors.append(topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: topConstant))
        }

        if let left = left {
            anchors.append(leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: left, constant: leftConstant))
        }

        if let bottom = bottom {
            anchors.append(bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -bottomConstant))
        }

        if let right = right {
            anchors.append(rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: right, constant: -rightConstant))
        }

        if widthConstant > 0 {
            anchors.append(widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: widthConstant))
        }

        if heightConstant > 0 {
            anchors.append(heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: heightConstant))
        }

        anchors.forEach({$0.isActive = true})

        return anchors
    }

    func addConstraintsWithFormat(format: String, views: UIView...) {
        var viewsDictionary = [String: UIView]()
        for (index, view) in views.enumerated() {
            let key = "v\(index)"
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            viewsDictionary[key] = view
        }

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if any other `view` is over `collectionView` in `UI debugger`.

Comment: @PGDev there is no view over collectionView :/

Comment: shoudn't you add `cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` before setting constraints

Comment: @RJE Should I? I'm not that experienced with swift, so I don't exactly know, if I have to do that. But I don't think that this could be problem or?

Comment: just try, sometimes it can cause issues on visible UI and touchable areas.

Comment: @RJE I just did, but it's still not working. Would you recommend to keep it in the code anyway? And does it matter where I add it (in declaration of cv or in viewDidLoad)?

Comment: @RJE I guess it is in `anchorWithConstantsToTop` method

Comment: @RajeshKumarR Yes you are right, I just checked it

Comment: @Kühlhausvogel Add `anchorToTop` and `anchorWithConstantsToTop` method codes

Comment: @Kühlhausvogel  What is code in anchorWithConstantsToTop() method ?

Comment: @Kühlhausvogel Don't add code in comments. Update the question

Comment: @RajeshKumarR I didn't know that, thanks :)

Comment: @Kühlhausvogel it's looking fine.

  try this what's happen tell me:- 
eventCollectionView.anchorToTop(view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor)

Comment: @Nimesh The difference to before is, that the collectionView is now directly under the navigation bar. Before it had a small distance. Same for bottom.

Comment: @Kühlhausvogel now get click event or not?

Comment: @Nimesh No unfortunately its still not working :(

Comment: @Kühlhausvogel Wait ,i will try in demo.

Comment: @Kühlhausvogel i get did select event same code use.Please clean and build.

Comment: @Nimesh Thank you very much for your help! It was a stupid mistake of mine. I have an extenstion of UIViewController: func HideKeyboard() which is working with UITapGestureRecognizer. I left it out in my question, because I didn't think this will be the problem, but I just didn't think far enough. Sorry for wasting your time. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem within an extension of UIViewController, which was using UITapGestureRecognizer. Because of this, the tap on the cell was not handled by the collectionView delegate but by the extension.